# How to estimate the individual components from a sum for a random process?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, multiple-regression

We have $N$ realisations of five individual, **IID** random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$ and $X_5$. We define another random variable $S = X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5$. Now, for a given $S$ generated from the same process, the individual components of which are unknown, how will we find the best estimates of $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$ and $X_5$?

EDIT 1: Each of the RV's $X_1$, $X_2$ up to $X_5$ are independent, but not identically distributed.

Comment: Are they normal?

Comment: @yoki they are not necessarily random. In fact, four of them are known to be skewed distributions, possibly Beta.

Comment: Your question states them to be iid. Do you mean instead that $X_1,...,X_5$ are not iid, but instead that if $V=(X_1,X_2,...,X_5)$ and we observe $V_1, ..., V_N$ that the $V_i$ are iid?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'best' in 'best estimates'? What's your criterion?

Comment: Well, I would put it this way- given the process data, i.e $N$ realisations of ${X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5}$ and $S=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5$, if I happen to know that there is a realisation $S_i$, what  will be the set of mean ${ X_{1i}, X_{2i}, X_{3i},X_{4i},X_{5i}}$ and the corresponding set of SD's. I hope that makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, you can use Bayes' theorem. The optimal (MMSE) estimator is given by 
$\hat{X} = E[X|S]$. Let $X=X_1$ (it doesn't matter which index as they are iid), so:
$$ f_{X|S}(x,s) = \frac{f_{S|X}(s,x)f_X(x)}{f_S(s)}$$ 
$f_X(x)$ is given, $f_S(s)$ is also given by an immediate calculation, and 
$f_{S|X}$ can be calculated via $P(S<s|X=x)=P(x+X_2+...+X_5<s)=P(X_2+...+X_5<s-x)=F_{S'}(s-x),$ where $S'$ is the partial sum of only four variables.

Finally, calculate via the conditional expectation definition: $\hat{X}=\int x f_{X|S}(x,s)dx$.

If your distribution is stable then you can probably get easier equations due to the iid sums present.

Comment: Thanks @yoki. But I made a mistake with the IID part. They are independent, but not identically distributed.

Comment: It does not matter for applying Bayes' theorem. You just have to keep track of the components.