# How to estimate the correlated individual components from a sum, for a random process?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, multiple-regression, conditional-expectation

Assume that there are $N$ realisations of five individual, random variables$X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$ and $X_5$, which in general **could be correlated**. We  define another random variable $S=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5$. Now, for a given $S$ generated from the same process, the individual components of which are unknown, how will we find the best (MMSE) estimates of $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$ and $X_5$?

PS: I had posted a related question, where the individual components happen to be independent, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124828/how-to-estimate-the-individual-components-from-a-sum-for-a-random-process). A Bayesian approach was suggested for that problem.